# Resource Not Available Tomcat 404 error when using Spring Java Config

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am getting

> "The requested resource (/SpringSecurity/welcome) is not available."

when using Spring Java Config

SpringInitializer.java

```
package com.security.config;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpringInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new String[] { "/" };
}
}
```

AppConfig.java

```
package com.security.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.security" })
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean
  public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
  }
}
```

HelloController class with Mappings

```
package com.security.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView welcomePage() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
    model.addObject("message", "This is welcome page!");
    model.setViewName("hello");
    return model;

}
}
```

1. My JSP files are available at "/WEB-INF/jsp/"
2. I am not getting any errors in console
3. I am using Tomcat 7

When i check my console i see

```
INFO: Mapped "{[/ || /welcome**],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.security.controller.HelloController.welcomePage()
```

so mapping seems to have been done. But still my tomcat server shows 404 error when i try to access using url : `http://localhost:8081/SpringSecurity/welcome`

I also tried "Clean Tomcat Working Directory". But i don't know the problem.

Comment: 1. Check that jsp are really in your war. 2. You can always debug from your Controller deeper to see, where the exception really happens.

Comment: do you get any logs when you make the request? or nothing at all?

Answer (score 0):

404 error is because the url you are triggering is not present or mapped. So kindly check the dispatcherservlet configuration you have done. Whether its mapped to /SpringSecurity or not. And also try giving /welcome alone in the controller instead of **.